# How do I setup django with apache so that my appliction is at the root url?

Tags: python, django, apache

I am new to django so please forgive me if this turns out to be obvious.

I have worked through the tutorials so I have a project (I called it "trydj") which has a application called "polls".  What I want to do is have polls served at the root, ie:

`http://www.example.com/`  would invoke the polls index view and

`http://www.example.com/details/` would invoke the polls details view.

What I don't want (but currently have) is:

`http://www.example.com/polls` and

`http://www.example.com/polls/details/`

I would also like to keep the ability to have other applications served at other sub-urls like the admin or other applications that I might create, ie:

`http://www.example.com/admin/` or

`http://www.example.com/anotherapp/`

I have everything just like it was at the end of the tutorials with the settings.py, manage.py, etc. at the project level and urls.py in both trydj and polls.

The urls.py in trydj has the following urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
   url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

   # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

and the urls.py in polls has the following urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$',
      ListView.as_view(
         queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
         template_name='polls/index.html'
      )
   ),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
      DetailView.as_view(
         model=Poll,
         template_name='polls/detail.html'
      )
   ),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',
      DetailView.as_view(
         model=Poll,
         template_name='polls/results.html'
      ),
      name='poll_results'
   ),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/vote/$',    'polls.views.vote'),
)
```

The apache config that I have created based on the django docs is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/trydj/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/django

<Directory /var/django/trydj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

My wsgi.py, again based on the django docs is:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/django/trydj')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/django/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I tried changing the relevant url regex in trydj.urls in various ways. The value `r'^'` sort of did the trick but then the application couldn't find its template files even if I moved them out of the polls directory and into the root of the templates folder.

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

to this

```
url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
```

So that all URLs that reach this point are passed through to your urls.py file in polls, rather than just ones prefixed with `polls/`.

Oh, and I should add that it's important to have this line where it is in the file (last), so that the other apps have a chance to recognise their own URLs before your polls app scoops them all up. If you swapped

Comment: I tried that (or thought I did, it was kinda late) but maybe I had other partial changes going when I tried this one. At any rate, I just tried it with a clean functioning implementation from the tutorial (glad I tagged) and it works like a charm. I did have to fix some of the url references in the templates but, once I discovered the <% url %> tag, that became very easy as well.  Thanks!